# Set Description with the powershell cmdlet in exchange 2013

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

How can we set the field "Description" in the general section with the powershell cmdlet ?

I am using a powershell command in c# to do my modification. I tried to use the command "set-ADUser", but it don't look like valid command to call...

here's the command I tried :

```
// create the PowerShell command
var command3 = new Command("Set-ADUser");
command3.Parameters.Add("Identity", userprincipalname);
command3.Parameters.Add("Description", description);
```

And I have this error :

```
The term 'Set-ADUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set-ADUser is from the ActiveDirectory module (RSAT tools).  The Exchange 2013 cmdlets use Set-User, but Description is not one it's parameters, so you can't set/change that using just the Exchange cmdlets.

Comment: Ok, so to use this command, I have to install this module on the exchange server ?

Comment: Yes. And you have to get it imported into the session that's running the command.  The management sessions Exchange provides are "No Language" constrained (they only recognize Exchange specific cmdlets), so you won't be able to do an import-module within one of those sessions.

Comment: I don't understand the import.. You mean in visual studio ? Thank you !

Comment: It's a module.  To use the cmdlets in the module it must be imported into the session or runspace the command is executed in.

Comment: I have to be at a meeting in 3 minutes. You might get quicker help posting a new question.......